# Html Not Rendering in Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-views, django-urls

I have a simple Html with CSS which I am trying to render using urls.py and views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
import re
# Create your views here.

# checks valid email
def is_valid_email(email):
    # Define the regex pattern for email validation
    pattern = r'^[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}$'
    return re.match(pattern, email)


def home(request):
    return render(request,'index.html')

def signup(request):
    return render(request,'signup.html')

def signin(request):
     return render(request, 'signin.html')
```

and the urls.py being

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home),
    path('signup/', views.signup),
    path('signin/', views.signin),
]
```

The home is rendering successfully but the signing and signup is not rendering showing the following error
[image: Render Error]

I have urls.py on project level as

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('app.urls'))
]
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

would appreciate any help!!!
My home is rendering perfectly but not the sign in and sign up.

Comment: 1) 
You don't need ".html" part. Just access "/signin" path.


2)
Remove last "/" from app urls.py.

Comment: Also templates are usually located in `appname/templates/appname` folder, [see example how to refer templates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/intro/tutorial03/#a-shortcut-render)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. 

You don't need ".html" part. Just access "/signin" path.

2)
Remove last "/" from app urls.py.

3)

Also templates are usually located in `appname/templates/appname` folder, from @Ivan 's comment.

Comment: #2 is irrelevant, you can make your routes however you wish (`whatever-route/` is a normal type of path as long as you access the URL with the `/` at the end). #1 is the problem, given that your app is actually finding your templates since you aren't getting an error that the template doesn't exist

Comment: oh yea thanks, While doing the frontend part I hardcoded the redirect in js to signin.html. Thanks Everyone